# Problem Analysis - Answer but no procedure - Differential Eq.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, problem-solving

I stumbled with this problem in a notebook that has been bothering me...The answer is written but there's no explanation nor a steb-by-step procedure or anything. If you know how to analyse the problem and create an equation from this, I will be very grateful!

A motor boat is moving at 10km/h being on tranquil waters. While moving, the motor was turned off and the speed of the boat went down to 6km/h.

A)Considering that the resistance force of the water is proportional to the speed of this, find the speed of the boat at 2 minutes of turning the motor off.

B)Find the travelled distance of the boat of 1 minute of having turned the motor off.

Answers: V= 0.467km/hr  Distance = 85.2m

Comment: "the speed of the boat went down to 6km/h" How much time did it take?

Comment: If you edit your question according to Did, I may vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

As given, the resistant force is:$$ f = -k \cdot \dot {v}$$
By Newton's second law, the equation of motion is:$$\dot{v}+\alpha\cdot {v} =0$$ 
where, $\alpha={k \over m}$, $m$ is the mass of the object that is not provided.
We can have the solution of the differential equation in the format:$$v=C_1 \cdot e^{\lambda t}$$
To satisfy the equation of motion, $\lambda=-\alpha$.

With $v(0)=10$, and $v(t_2)=6$, we have $C_1=10$ and $C_1 \cdot e^{-\alpha t_2}=6$.

Therefore, $$e^{-\alpha t_2}={6 \over 10}$$

We must have the value of $t_2$ to determine the value of $\alpha$, but it is not provided in the original question.

Inversely, according one of the answer, $t_2$ must be 20 seconds.

We now have:$$v=10 \cdot e^{-\alpha t}$$

where $\alpha=180\ln({5\over3})$

Integrate $v$ to $x$, we have:$$x=\int_0^t{v}dt={10 \over \alpha}(1-e^{-\alpha t})$$

Comment: Thank you very much! But I've got a couple of questions, sorry. What does lambda mean here? and can does x˙ mean x1 or x'? Im sorry, Im new to this notation.
Also, your answer is different to the one in the book....

Comment: Sorry, didn't tag you in my previous comment.

Comment: Or what does e^lambda * t2 mean?(What does it stand for...)?

Comment: Ok, x's are x'' and x' according to my notation. But what does lambda mean here?

Comment: I have modified. $\lambda$ is a parameter for linear differential equations here. (See wiki or book). If you still have any question after my reversion, please comment.